# How to include external parameters in aws cloudformation template?

Tags: shell, aws-cloudformation

Hi I am creating cloud formation project to create resources and infra structure for my project. I am trying to append branch_name to my stack names. Below is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z "${STACK_SUFFIX-}" ]]; then
  # Jenkins - Multibranch Pipelines
  if [[ -n "${BRANCH_NAME-}" ]]; then
    if [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" != "master" ]]; then
      STACK_SUFFIX="-${BRANCH_NAME}"
    fi
  # GNU/UNIX
  elif [[ -n "${USER-}" ]]; then
    STACK_SUFFIX="-${USER}"
  # Windows - Git Bash
  elif [[ -n "${USERNAME-}" ]]; then
    STACK_SUFFIX="-${USERNAME}"
  else
    echo "Could not cleanly determine stack suffix!" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
  export CFN_STACK_SUFFIX=${STACK_SUFFIX-}
fi
```

I have one constants file which I have added

```
stacksuffix: "{{ CFN_STACK_SUFFIX }}"
```

Below is my cloud formation template.

```
 SecurityGroups:
        # yamllint disable-line rule:line-length
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub 'location-agent-sg${stacksuffix}::MerchWebServicesLoadBalancerSG'
```

whenever I check in cloud formation through jenkins, I dont get branch name attached to it. Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: There is something missing in your question. What's the relation between the bash code and the piece of template you posted?

Comment: Hi Daniel. I want to add branch name during runtime. stacksuffix is branch name.